# DL360 G2 SNMP drive failure location

Tags: logging, hp, snmp, hp-smart-array, scsi

I've got this service call with the snmp information provided below, about the drive failing in HP DL360 G2 server:

```
Error log Event Type: Error

Event Source: Storage Agents

Event Category: Events 

Event ID: 1064

Date: 2013-06-07

Time: 02:21:35

User: N/A

Description:  Compaq Drive Array Physical Drive Status Change.  The physical drive in **slot 0, port 2, bay 1** with serial number "6LQASCX8800B223431U", has a new status of 3.

(Drive status values: 1=other, 2=ok, 3=failed, 4=predictiveFailure)

[SNMP TRAP: 3029 in CPID]
```

How to determine which physical drive is it? DL360 G2 has two drive slots: left (SCSI ID 0) and right (SCSI 1). Does this SNMP trap enumerates bays from 0 as well or from 1? iLO doesn't provide information about drives connected, HP Array configuration utility lists drives in slots, but can't indicate which one is it (array configuration utility on startup indeed can do that, but restarting the server is not an option).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "HP Array configuration utility lists drives in slots, but can't indicate which one is it", huh? The ACU will indicate which drive is failed. Click on the exclamation point at the top.

Comment: This is an SNMP trap error, not the servers. Both of the drives are operating normally. The logs are clear. The trap sent the error and the owner of the server wants the drive replaced, but since neither of them is flashing I can't distinguish which one is the bay 1.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I can't see how this is relevant. I don't have the information about OS on the site, I've got only the error. I've tested mine DL360 and installed ACU on Windows Server 2003 just to check if the numeration format there would be the same as in SNMP message.

Comment: The OS is relevant because I'd give you the right `hpacucli` or `cpqacuxe` command to identify the drive, check errors counters and identify the drive accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no excuse to still be running anything on a 12 year-old server with parallel SCSI...

Either way, HP drive slots are numbered from ZERO. SNMP will follow the same convention because there's an HP/Compaq-specific SNMP hook in use here.

```
Smart Array 6400 in Slot 3                (sn: P57820G9SQ90KM)
   array A (Parallel SCSI, Unused Space: 0 MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (410.2 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1:0   (port 1:id 0 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1:1   (port 1:id 1 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1:2   (port 1:id 2 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1:3   (port 1:id 3 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1:4   (port 1:id 4 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1:5   (port 1:id 5 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
```

Comment: Indeed, keeping that old piece of history is reckless, but until they pay I have no questions :). So the right drive it is. Thanks for your replies.